# javacv-linux-x86_64.jar with libopencv_core.so.2.3

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop, javacv

Does anyone knows link to download javacv-linux-x86_64.jar with libopencv_core.so.2.3? I have downloaded one but that is with libopencv_core.so.2.4 so my application is throwing error: (libopencv_core.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory).
Thanks!

Comment: Add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting Java. Also, get `libopencv_core.so.2.3` your application isn't linked with`libopencv_core.so.2.4`

Comment: Yeah that my point. From where can I get libopencv_core.so.2.3? I added that to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but as I said the jar contains `libopencv_core.so.2.3` thats why it is throwing error. I could not find javacv-linux-x86_64.jar with libopencv_core.so.2.3.

Comment: Your exception says 2.3 cannot open. Where did 2.4 come from?

Comment: I guess it is coming from javacv-linux-x86_64.jar as it contains all the related libopencv files.

Comment: When I run sudo ldconfig -v, in the output I have file with name like libopencv_core.so.2.4 -> libopencv_core.so.2.4.5. Thats why I told that it finds 2.4 but not 2.3.

Comment: The program requires 2.3, it clearly will not work with 2.4. Sounds like you need to find another version. No I do not use this software myself. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah now you see my point. Anyways thanks. Lets see if someone else know the link to download 2.3 version.